# ToggleButton pushed out to the right

Tags: c#, wpf

I've copied the code form this [article](http://marcangers.com/animated-switch-togglebutton-style-in-wpf/) on how to make a iOS style toggle button.

It works well, the only issue is that it is sitting pushed out to the right, and it seems that a large amount of margin is moving it...

[image: toggle button]

```
<ToggleButton 
    Style="{StaticResource AnimatedSwitch}" 
    Height="30" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Width="50" 
    Margin="-20, 4, 0, 5"
    Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" 
    Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
```

Why is this style requiring so much margin to get it to sit so far off to the right... I would have thought that you would want the control to take up the entire space of its parent and scale with it?

Here's the code from the referenced article for the sake of completeness:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style x:Key="AnimatedSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFB" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EAEAEB" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                     <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
                           <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="0" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                           <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="15" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                           <Border Canvas.Left="10" Width="15" Height="20" Name="rect416927" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0.5,0,0.5"/>
                           <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"  Canvas.Left="0" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.3">
                              <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                 <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                              </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                              <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                                 <DropShadowBitmapEffect Softness="0.1" ShadowDepth="0.7" Direction="270" Color="#BBBBBB"/>
                              </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                           </Ellipse>
                        </Canvas>
                     </Viewbox>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
                           <Trigger.EnterActions>
                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                 <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#52D468" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#41C955" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                       <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                       <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="15" KeySpline="0, 1, 0.6, 1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                              </BeginStoryboard>
                           </Trigger.EnterActions>
                           <Trigger.ExitActions>
                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                 <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FAFAFB" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#EAEAEB" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                       <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="15"/>
                                       <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0" KeySpline="0, 0.5, 0.5, 1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                              </BeginStoryboard>
                           </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource AnimatedSwitch}" Height="80"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be in this line:

```
<Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
```

It does not take into account how the button is moved when checked (the knob is translated by 15 pixels along x). So it must be:

```
<Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="35" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
```

Now you may use

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource AnimatedSwitch}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="80"/>
```

in order to position the button exactly at the right edge.

Comment: I don't quite understand the point about `how the button is moved when checked`

Comment: Ohhh no I get it now

Comment: (it's the ControlTemplate's trigger on IsChecked == true)

Answer (score 1):

I read the template of the toggle button and here, as you can see, there is a canvas and inside it there are defined some ellipses.

The second is shifted of 15 from the first one. Doing this, goes outside the surface of the canvas that has a width of 20.

```
<Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
      <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="0" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
      <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="15" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
```

try changing the canvas **width** to **35**. Like this:

```
<Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="35" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
```