# Toggle button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, toggle

I am new to wpf . I want to create toggle button like

[image: Toggle button]

how can I achieve this. should I need to use two buttons and on click of each I need to disable other one. or there is  anything else like toggle button in wpf. what is best way to achieve this.. any suggestion appreciated.Thanks

Comment: please share some code on what you have accomplished by now

Comment: There was a question about toggle-buttons not so long ago, with some adjustment, it might fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220630/togglebutton-pushed-out-to-the-right

Comment: @ViVi Toggle ON OFF is too broad?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a quick Version. The trick is to use a style.

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="on" Width="25" Height="25" Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="2,0,0,4" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="onText" Text="On" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="off" Width="25" Height="25" Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="0,2,4,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="offText" Text="Off" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="on" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="onText" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="off" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="offText" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

ToggleButton call:

```
    <ToggleButton 
        Content="ON LINE MODE" 
        Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle1}"/>
```

## **Preview**

[image]

Comment: Kindly include the enclosing <Window.Resources> tag

Comment: ToggleButtons are so easy to screw up and this implementation makes two classic mistakes.  1. The "enabled" value is on the left.  2. The "enabled" color is stil present when disabled.

Comment: I agree with you on both points. However, she only asked how something like this could be implemented and back then I made a "quick and dirty" version. ✌