# Can a WPF animated button be reversed on the second click without codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

Im using powershell w/WPF. I have the following example code that produces a button that animates by moving to the right when clicked, I am trying to figure out the best way of approaching clicking it a second time to animate in reverse back to the original position.

ButtonTest.ps1:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore
[xml]$xaml='
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoMouseOverButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="MovableButton" Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#EEEEEE" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="70" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">ClickMe<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="ButtonAnimation" From="70" To="207" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard></EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>'
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$Button1=$Window.FindName("MovableButton")
$Button1.Add_Click({
    write-host ButtonClicked
})
$window.Show()
$appContext=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

EDIT: Not an answer to the question per se, but I ended up going with a codebehind and got it working in PS until I piece together a working pure WPF solution, this uses a second button, which is hidden, and they toggle hide/visible their counterparts at the end of their animations, and added FillBehavior="Stop" so that they reset to their original positions when "Completed" is detected from the animation, this gives the appearance of a single button moving back and forth.

WorkingButton.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore
[xml]$xaml='
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoMouseOverButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="MovableButton1" Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#EEEEEE" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="70" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">Button1<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="ButtonAnimation1" From="70" To="207" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard></EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="MovableButton2" Canvas.Left="207" Canvas.Top="0" Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Light" BorderBrush="#111111" Foreground="#EEEEEE" Background="#111111" Height="18" Width="70" Template="{StaticResource NoMouseOverButtonTemplate}">Button2<Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Name="ButtonAnimation2" From="207" To="70" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard></EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>'
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$Button1=$Window.FindName("MovableButton1")
$Button2=$Window.FindName("MovableButton2")
$ButtonAnimation1=$Window.FindName("ButtonAnimation1")
$ButtonAnimation2=$Window.FindName("ButtonAnimation2")
$Button1.Add_Click({
    write-host FirstButtonClicked
})
$Button2.Add_Click({
    write-host SecondButtonClicked
})
$ButtonAnimation1.Add_Completed({
    write-host AnimationCompleted
    $Button1.Visibility="Hidden"
    $Button2.Visibility="Visible"
})
$ButtonAnimation2.Add_Completed({
    write-host AnimationCompleted
    $Button1.Visibility="Visible"
    $Button2.Visibility="Hidden"
})
$window.Show()
$appContext=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext
[void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run($appContext)
```

Comment: Are you using the default theme or your own? If second, that sounds like a checkbox/switch which ON state happens to look like a button-moved-to-right, and the OFF state is like a button-moved-to-left. That way you could do it without code-behind.

Comment: The button is going to be a menubar item that slides from its position when clicked to the middle of the menubar, and a listbox becomes visible under it when it does.  The intended behavior is on the second click, im closing the listbox, but I want the button to fly back to its original position on the menubar.. To frame the question better. I am making this in notepad and what I posted is a snippet I can use if a working example or suggestion is given - It's for the playlist button for this - https://github.com/illsk1lls/PowerPlayer

Comment: I get it. I am saying that the actual element you (probably) want is what is usually called a toggle, not a button. A button will require some minimal code (a bound property at least) to do what you want. A toggle/checkbox/radiobutton (which one - depends on how your menu should handle multiple things being selected) with a custom "skin" will not. The value of that toggle should be tied to the listbox state (expanded/collapsed)

Comment: This question has a rough implementation (in your case you would just ditch the background I suppose, and make the left-to-right size much bigger): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321275/toggle-button-in-wpf

Comment: Do you think using RoutedEvent Completed for the storyboard would work? And having 2 buttons that hide eachother?

Comment: I don't think so, because don't you want that "right" state to have a specific, dynamic text (the same as on the pressed button)? Also, it is  a very fragile way - events are not meant for that... Honestly, look into toggles in wpf. You want a button with 2 states - that's a toggle. It is already implemented, no need to invent your own..

Comment: @defaultUsernameN I looked at toggle and I couldnt figure out how to get the sliding animation embedded, so I went with codebehind, it was simple, but PS/WPF codebehind documentation is hard to come by.. probably for good reason - My working solution (Until I learn more) is added to the bottom of OP, Thanks for helping